# Confusion related to linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model

I learned a linear regression model with some input xs and output ys. My ys are always positive. However, now when I test the model on my test data, I get negative values for ys. I know I can either take the absolute value of ys or make them 0. But that's not the right way to do it. What is the correct approach to deal with this situation?

Comment: If you fit a model of a straight line with constant gaussian error to a bounded variable, obviously this is going to happen. The correct way to deal with it is not to fit a model you know to be wrong, but one that's at least plausible. If y's can only be positive, you don't fit a model that says they can be negative.

Answer (score 3):

There is not necessarily anything you have to do. Predicted values have error and sometimes the error will make a small positive value a negative one.

If you show some of your data and tell us more, perhaps showing code, we can see if there actually is a problem.

Comment: There is also the situation when one tries to use the model to a range of `x` which is far away from the sample used to adjust the model. Is that right?

Comment: That could be.... I don't think it's what's happening here, based on question, but it could be. The question has very little detail.

Comment: Although there are no negative values for y in your data, is a negative value for y possible (and meaningful)? (eg. if your outcome was temperature (in Celsius), negative values are possible and meaningful along with positive values)

Comment: @MattReichenbach. No negative values are not possible. I am now transforming my output to the range [0 1] and using logsig activation function for output